# Citroen C3 Picasso HDI 1.6 - Oil Consumption Question

Tags: engine, oil, citroen, picasso

I just bought a 1.6 HDI Picasso C3.  After driving 1000 km i noticed it consumed about 1/8 of oil on the oil measuring stick.

***my question is how much liters does the stick measure?***

***is half a stick is half an oil tank or half a liter?***

***and is this oil consumption normal for an engine that has done 110 thousand km?***

Comment: When you checked the oil level, was the engine hot out cold? This question applies for both occasions when you are comparing oil levels. If one time the engine was hot and the other time the engine was cold, this can have a role to play in explaining why you see so much variation in reading.

Comment: Cold both times.levelled as well.does the dip stick measure the whole tank or just a liter?

Answer (score 2):

Dip stick operating range is typically a liter (or quart).  I would say this level of oil loss is acceptable.  If you can find the source of the leak it would be best to fix it, but it is not going to hurt anything as long as you keep the oil level within the operating range.